# Grouped barplots

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe data in R which looks like

```
construct       category        count
0       insert  327
1       insert  320
2       insert  311
3       insert  309
4       insert  297
0       rev_insert      216
1       rev_insert      214
2       rev_insert      211
3       rev_insert      220
4       rev_insert      228
```

I want to make a grouped barplot of data$counts for every construct with 2 bars together for each of the categories "insert" and "rev_insert".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# dummy data
df <- read.table(text="construct       category        count
0       insert  327
1       insert  320
2       insert  311
3       insert  309
4       insert  297
0       rev_insert      216
1       rev_insert      214
2       rev_insert      211
3       rev_insert      220
4       rev_insert      228", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
# plot
ggplot(df,aes(construct,count,fill=category)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]